# Java: Spring MVC - How do I access the updated model in controller action?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am learning Spring MVC 3 and am not a Java expert in general. I have a few questions

1. From what I can tell `ModelAndView` is not used anymore. I also see these two:

   - `org.springframework.ui.Model`
   - `org.springframework.ui.ModelMap`

What's the difference between `ModelMap` and `Model`? Is one of them old style like `ModelAndView`?

1. How can I pass form data back to the controller? Here's what I have so far:

**VIEW**

```
<form action="/KSC/users/update" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" id="fEdit">

                            <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="${record.id}" />

                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label for="userName" class="control-label"></label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" value="${record.userName}" data-validation-engine="validate[required]" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label for="email" class="control-label"></label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="${record.email}" data-validation-engine="validate[required,custom[email]]" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="control-group">
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                    <a href="/KSC/users" class="btn">Cancel</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

**EDIT ACTION**

Here's what I originally passed to the above View from the Edit action:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/edit/{id}")
    public String edit(ModelMap model, @PathVariable("id") int userId) {
        KCSUser user = service.find(userId);
        model.addAttribute("record", user);
        return "user/edit";
    }
```

**CONTROLLER UPDATE ACTION**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/update")
    public String update(ModelMap model) {
        //TODO
    }
```

I need to access the updated model data so i can save it to my DB. Ideally if it could map directly to a `KSCUser` object that would be nice.. but if not, then a `Model` or `ModelMap` would be fine too. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/update")
    public String update(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("record") KCSUser record) {

        if (record.getId() == 0) {
            service.insert(record);
        }
        else {
            KCSUser existing = service.find(record.getId());
            existing.setUserName(record.getUserName());
            existing.setEmail(record.getEmail());
            //etc...
            service.update(existing);
        }

        return index(model);
    }
```

Comment: this was without any command object in the JSP, and without the `id` field being in the JSP?

Answer (score 4):

> **How can I pass form data back to the controller?**

just change the signature of you update method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/update")
public String update(KSCUser user, ModelMap model) {
    // ...
}
```

spring will create a instance of KSCUser and fill the properties based on the name attribute of the input field. so if you have a input field like `<input type="text" name="username" />`, spring will try to call `setUsername` on the instance of KSCUser.

you could also change the signature of you method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/update")
public String update(@RequestParam("username") final String username) {
    // ...
}
```

spring then would inject the value of the input field with name `username`.

or you could change the signature of your method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/update")
public String update(Map<String, String> params) {
    // ...
}
```

spring then would inject all request parameters in the `params` map. you can access the username like this: `params.get("username")`.

for the sake of completeness... you could change the signature of you method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/update")
public String update(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // ...
}
```

spring then would just inject a instance of `HttpServletRequest` and you could access you request parameters like you would do with vanila servlet api.

> **Ideally if it could map directly to a KSCUser object that would be nice.. but if not, then a Model or ModelMap would be fine too**

when you inject `ModelMap` only (like you do in your `update` method), it will not contain the request parameters (except you use [@SeessionAttributes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttributes.html)) and you will not be able to access them this way.

> **What's the difference between ModelMap and Model**

good question. the javadoc for ModelMap says:

> Check out the Model interface for a Java-5-based interface variant
>   that serves the same purpose

**imho**: the `Model` interface looks like it was intended only for adding objects to the model (not reading from model)... just like it is the case in your `edit` method. But then there is a `asMap` method, which grant you access to the content of the model.

i have never used the `Model` interface myself. Always inject the `ModelMap`.

Comment: I already got mine working a slightly different way, but this is interesting info, so +1 from me anyway. Thanks.

Comment: I did. See the other answer.  :)

Comment: @Matt oh, did not see, it was your own answer :)